# Loop array from json

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, loops

How i can use **loop** **array** from **json**? I created **struct** from **json** and me need use **loop** for load images in **collectionView**. My images are in **firebase** and have **struct**:

```
object1:
    name: "object1Name"
    images:
        image0: 
        "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/photostudios-973d3.appspot.com/o/studioImages%2Fcross%20%2Bstudio%2FCROSS%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B5%2FCross%2BSpace%2FCross%2BSpace.jpg?alt=media&token=cbcc2e9a-580f-4266-9f5e-4e86bb5714e2"
        image1:
        "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/photostudios-973d3.appspot.com/o/studioImages%2Fcross%20%2Bstudio%2FCROSS%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B5%2FCross%2BSpace%2FCross%2BSpace1.jpg?alt=media&token=76f0e8f3-1278-4fe4-802a-9cf3f934d016"
        image2:
        "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/photostudios-973d3.appspot.com/o/studioImages%2Fcross%20%2Bstudio%2FCROSS%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B5%2FCross%2BSpace%2FCross%2BSpace2.jpg?alt=media&token=3256d061-6e0e-4001-9aa6-4eba9e25da1b"
object2:
    name: object2Name
    images:
        image0: 
        "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/photostudios-973d3.appspot.com/o/studioImages%2Fcross%20%2Bstudio%2FCROSS%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B5%2FCross%2BSpace%2FCross%2BSpace.jpg?alt=media&token=cbcc2e9a-580f-4266-9f5e-4e86bb5714e2"
        image1:
        "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/photostudios-973d3.appspot.com/o/studioImages%2Fcross%20%2Bstudio%2FCROSS%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B5%2FCross%2BSpace%2FCross%2BSpace1.jpg?alt=media&token=76f0e8f3-1278-4fe4-802a-9cf3f934d016"
        image2:
        "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/photostudios-973d3.appspot.com/o/studioImages%2Fcross%20%2Bstudio%2FCROSS%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B5%2FCross%2BSpace%2FCross%2BSpace2.jpg?alt=media&token=3256d061-6e0e-4001-9aa6-4eba9e25da1b"
```

My struct in xCode:

```
struct object {

    private var json: [String: Any]

    init(json: [String: Any]) {
        self.json = json
    }
    // on this not pay attention
    var name: String? {
        return json["name"] as? String
    }
    // How to write code to get an array of images???
```

And how use my struct in collectionView?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "detailCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailSearchCollectionViewCell

    // What should I write here?

    return cell
}
```

Big thanks for help. This is my first experience with **json** file, do not judge strictly for the stupid question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
 var images: [String: Any]? {
        return json["images"] as? [String: Any]
   }
```

And get by specific image by `object.images["image0"]`

OR

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "detailCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailSearchCollectionViewCell

    // What should I write here?
    // Add this line 
    print("Image URL is = \(object.images["image\(indexPath.row)"])")

    return cell
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, it so I will be able to get one image? Because in console I have only printed one image, not image0, image1 and image2

Comment: @onpro I added one line in `cellForItemAt` you can try with it,

Comment: i get only first image from array. First image is image0

Comment: oh, sorry, my misstake, i forgot `return ...count` in `numberOfItemInSection`. All work, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `class` or `struct` rather than Array of dictionary

You can easily convert your json to swift4 types using 
https://quicktype.io/

Example

For you json

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "objects":{
            "name":"object1Name",
            "images":[
               {
                  "image0":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/photostudios-973d3.appspot.com/o/studioImages%2Fcross%20%2Bstudio%2FCROSS%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B5%2FCross%2BSpace%2FCross%2BSpace.jpg?alt=media&token=cbcc2e9a-580f-4266-9f5e-4e86bb5714e2"
               },
               {
                  "image1":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/photostudios-973d3.appspot.com/o/studioImages%2Fcross%20%2Bstudio%2FCROSS%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B5%2FCross%2BSpace%2FCross%2BSpace1.jpg?alt=media&token=76f0e8f3-1278-4fe4-802a-9cf3f934d016"
               },
               {
                  "image2":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/photostudios-973d3.appspot.com/o/studioImages%2Fcross%20%2Bstudio%2FCROSS%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B5%2FCross%2BSpace%2FCross%2BSpace2.jpg?alt=media&token=3256d061-6e0e-4001-9aa6-4eba9e25da1b"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Your classes for swift 4 Would be

```
    import Foundation

struct DataObjects: Codable {
    let data: [Datum]
}

struct Datum: Codable {
    let objects: Objects
}

struct Objects: Codable {
    let images: [Image]
    let name: String
}

struct Image: Codable {
    let image0: String?
    let image1: String?
    let image2: String?
}

// MARK: Top-level extensions -

extension DataObjects {
    static func from(json: String, using encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) -> DataObjects? {
        guard let data = json.data(using: encoding) else { return nil }
        return from(data: data)
    }

    static func from(data: Data) -> DataObjects? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try? decoder.decode(DataObjects.self, from: data)
    }

    static func from(url urlString: String) -> DataObjects? {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return nil }
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else { return nil }
        return from(data: data)
    }

    var jsonData: Data? {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        return try? encoder.encode(self)
    }

    var jsonString: String? {
        guard let data = self.jsonData else { return nil }
        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    }
}

// MARK: Codable extensions -

extension DataObjects {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data = "data"
    }
}

extension Datum {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case objects = "objects"
    }
}

extension Objects {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case images = "images"
        case name = "name"
    }
}

extension Image {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case image0 = "image0"
        case image1 = "image1"
        case image2 = "image2"
    }
}

// Helpers

class JSONNull: Codable {
    public init() {
    }

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if !container.decodeNil() {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONNull.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull"))
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encodeNil()
    }
}
```

Now you can access

```
  let dataObjects = DataObjects.from(json: jsonString)!
```

**HOW TO USE THIS**

in your datasource

you can `return dataObjects.data.count`

in `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {`

you can easily get image Array like

`dataObjects.data[indexPath.row]. objects.images`

That's simpler safer and faster way to do it

Comment: Thanks, but for me it's difficult way, I would like an easier way to get my array. I'm sure he is have :)

Comment: @onpro Please check edit i have updated answer with way to use it is easy for you now